# List available tests with py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I can't find a way to list the tests which I can call with `py.test -k PATTERN`

How can I see the list of the available tests?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can also use `--collect-only`, this will show a tree-like structure of the collected nodes.  Usually one can simply `-k` on the names of the Function nodes.

Comment: You can also use of -k and --collect-only together. It will collect all the tests which match the expression.

Answer (score 18):

You should use the flag `--collect-only`. If you are using `pytest` [5.3.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/changelog.html#pytest-5-3-0-2019-11-19) or newer use `--co`.

### pytest 5.3.0+

```sh
pytest --co
```

## previous versions

```sh
pytest --collect-only
```

You can use this flag among other flags, so in your case `pytest --co -k PATTERN`.

Answer (score 9):

Both *--collect-only* and *--setup-plan* will print out your test files and individual tests.

`--collect-only` (or `--co`) prints in a <[*type*] [*name*]> format

```
pytest --collect-only
# or
pytest --co

# <Module test_file.py>
#   <Function test__my_awesome_code_does_the_awesome_thing>
```

`--setup-plan` is more verbose and prints the entire test-run plan (including any setup, teardown, and fixtures used for each test). It also prints the entire path for each test.

```
pytest --setup-plan

# tests/test_file.py
#     SETUP    [...]
#     tests/test_file.py::test__my_awesome_code_does_the_awesome_thing (fixtures used: [...])
#     TEARDOWN [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

-v verbose tells you which test cases are run, i.e. which did match your PATTERN.

Comment: I want to list the tests, without running any.